# Smoothing CSS3 Animations

Tags: css, css-transitions

When using `transition` or `animation` the resulting animation is not smooth and is "jumpy" in both IE10 and Chrome *(not tested any other)* when dealing with margins but opacity transitions seem to be fine.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2frFx/2/) is a link to the fiddle. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2frFx/3/) is another example.

It looks to me as the browsers are not using decimals when sliding down, but when fading opacity they are.

How would I go about smoothing the animation? I've considered using jQuery for doing the animation but I'd still be using CSS animations for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use images in their original size. If you rescale them, they might look uneven, especially in CSS animations. If you have images in your animation that are of a higher resolution than needed, you should resize them.

Comment: As shown in the fiddles, it's not just images that it occurs to.

Comment: Okay. Anyways, I'll leave this answer here, it might be useful for someone else.